# How to create a dropdown with 'option group' on Grails 4?

Tags: grails, dropdown, html-select

I wanna create a **dropdown** with **option group**. Controller return a list which is options items and get the list on **GSP** page. I need to populated that option item with option group.

```
<select class="" name="name" id="name">     
                <g:each in="${list}" var="opt">
                  
                </g:each>
</select>
```

Anybody can give an example with backend code. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `<g:select ...>` tag.

```
<g:select optionKey="id" optionValue="title"
          name="book.title" from="${bookList}" />
```

See https://gsp.grails.org/latest/ref/Tags/select.html.